# Sora front derailleur friction shifter

Tags: shifter, derailleur-front

I have Sora front derailleur (bottom-pull), and I want to use friction shifter with it. I installed Dura Ace bar end shifters (on thumb shifter mount).

No matter how I adjust the tension the shifter doesn't hold position. It always pulls to the smallest chain ring. I wonder is there anybody who come across something this.

I begin to think the combination of derailleur and shifter is not compatible.
Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[You may be able to adjust the friction](http://forums.roadbikereview.com/components-wrenching/front-derailleur-return-spring-too-strong-194993.html). Adjusting the tension in the cable probably won't help.

This is a bit of a known issue with some combinations:

- https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/1069395-shimano-rd-5701-hard-shift-friction-shifters.html
- http://forums.roadbikereview.com/components-wrenching/shimano-friction-shifter-adjustment-183941.html

Unfortunately you're unlikely to be able to find a weaker return spring to fit.

Comment: It could also be a myriad of cable/installation issues before you get to the shifter. But the friction on the shifter should go up. I've heard the return spring argument before, but I'm not sure I buy it; I think it might just be people switching from old derailleurs to new ones and noticing things are a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Batman you could be right and my experience of road components is still limited. But I've got a Sora triple FD on my tourer and (from new) it feels like it has quite a strong spring. This is based on the force needed to shift against the spring with brifters. It feels like a clean, smooth movement. Also shifting by hand when cleaning takes more force than on my other (flat bar) bikes.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Chris H. The Sora FD spring seems strong, pulling by hand require quite a bit of force. I'm going to try few other FDs and report back. Thanks all.